# Rust lifetimes in async wrapper for sync code

Tags: asynchronous, rust, lifetime, rust-futures

I am trying to create a `Stream` using a camera with a blocking capture method. The blocking call is wrapped with [`blocking::unblock`](https://docs.rs/blocking/1.2.0/blocking/fn.unblock.html).

```rust
use futures::stream;
use rscam::{Camera, Config};

fn frame_stream() -> impl stream::Stream {
    let mut camera = Camera::new("/dev/video0").unwrap();

    camera.start(&Config {
        interval: (1, 30),
        resolution: (1280, 720),
        format: b"H264",
        ..Default::default()
    }).unwrap();

    stream::unfold(camera, |c| async move {
        let frame = blocking::unblock(|| c.capture().unwrap()).await;
        
        Some((frame, c))
    })
}
```

Compiling gives this error message:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `c`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/lib.rs:15:39
   |
15 |         let frame = blocking::unblock(|| c.capture().unwrap()).await;
   |                                       ^^ - `c` is borrowed here
   |                                       |
   |                                       may outlive borrowed value `c`
   |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'static`
  --> src/lib.rs:15:21
   |
15 |         let frame = blocking::unblock(|| c.capture().unwrap()).await;
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `c` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
15 |         let frame = blocking::unblock(move || c.capture().unwrap()).await;
   |                                       ++++

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `c` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:17:22
   |
15 |         let frame = blocking::unblock(|| c.capture().unwrap()).await;
   |                     ------------------------------------------
   |                     |                 |  |
   |                     |                 |  borrow occurs due to use in closure
   |                     |                 borrow of `c` occurs here
   |                     argument requires that `c` is borrowed for `'static`
16 |         
17 |         Some((frame, c))
   |                      ^ move out of `c` occurs here
```

How can I guarantee to the compiler that the reference to `c` taken in the closure will still be valid? I assume it will be, since execution of the closure is awaited before `c` is returned.

## Solution

```rust
stream::unfold(camera, |c| async move {
    Some(
        blocking::unblock(|| {
            (c.capture().unwrap(), c)
        }).await
    )
})
```

Comment: Please include the full error as seen by `cargo check` and include the missing definitions or imported crate items (like `Camera` and `blocking`). Its hard to answer without having all the pieces.

Comment: It didn't seem that relevant, but here you go.

Comment: `blocking::unblock` explicitly requires that the passed-in function is valid for the static lifetime, so it won't be able to borrow `c`. There's not much of a way around it other than storing `c` in an `Arc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the camera into the inner closure, then return it once the frame capture is complete:

```rust
    stream::unfold(camera, |c| async move {
        Some(blocking::unblock(|| move {
            let frame = c.capture().unwrap()).await;
            (frame,c)
        })
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, worked after some syntax fixes.

Answer (score 0):

`.await` does not guarantee liveness. This is the general problem of [scoped async tasks](https://rust-lang.github.io/wg-async/vision/roadmap/scopes.html). Futures can be canceled at any time. Consider:

```
let future = async {
    let local = 123;
    blocking::unblock(|| local).await;
};

// Poll `future`, but only once.
futures::block_on(async move { futures::poll!(future) });
```

We started a task using local data, then dropped the future. The task continues executing but the local data is gone. For this reason, there is currently no sound way to expose an async API allowing using local data similar to [scoped threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html). You have to use `'static` data, for example by wrapping in `Arc`.

See also [`blocking` issue #4](https://github.com/smol-rs/blocking/issues/4).